# how to show web API data in python gui app

Tags: python, xml, desktop-application

I want to develop a python GUI desktop app for local/state newspapers. For news data for example `Hindustan Times`, I am using `HindustanTimes/RSS` API data.
It sends data but how I show that data (articles, images etc ) in my GUI python desktop app?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask.

Comment: you are overthinking this
Get out a piece of paper and pencil, draw out a picture of what you want your gui to look like, pairing the controls needed with the type of data
get the data, from the api... 
create a function to get new data every hour, etc, as per your requirement
parse the data
display the data you want using gui controls, text, etc

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are wanting, but I'm thinking this might be a great resource for you.  I'm not sure if it covers implementing a GUI, but it at least goes over interacting between Python and html/javascript which would be required for such an endeavor.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.